# How to fix dependency conflict issue while installing php-pecl-sphinx.x86_64 on php56w

Tags: php, dependencies, sphinx

I have installed php56w using webtatic repository https://webtatic.com/packages/php56/

but when i tried to install available php-pecl-sphinx.x86_64 package on my linux system

```
Linux production 3.10.0-123.8.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Sep 22 19:06:58 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

i am getting dependency conflict error like this

**important line:**

```
Error: php56w-common conflicts with php-common-5.4.16-23.el7_0.3.x86_64
```

**more details:**

```
[root@production basesite]# yum install php-pecl-sphinx.x86_64
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.1000mbps.com
 * epel: mirror.nl.leaseweb.net
 * extras: mirror.netrouting.net
 * updates: mirror.netrouting.net
 * webtatic: uk.repo.webtatic.com
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-pecl-sphinx.x86_64 0:1.3.2-1.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php(zend-abi) = 20100525-64 for package: php-pecl-sphinx-1.3.2-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php(api) = 20100412-64 for package: php-pecl-sphinx-1.3.2-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /usr/bin/pecl for package: php-pecl-sphinx-1.3.2-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /usr/bin/pecl for package: php-pecl-sphinx-1.3.2-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libsphinxclient-0.0.1.so()(64bit) for package: php-pecl-sphinx-1.3.2-1.el7.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libsphinxclient.x86_64 0:2.1.5-1.el7 will be installed
---> Package php-common.x86_64 0:5.4.16-23.el7_0.3 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libzip.so.2()(64bit) for package: php-common-5.4.16-23.el7_0.3.x86_64
---> Package php-pear.noarch 1:1.9.4-21.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-xml for package: 1:php-pear-1.9.4-21.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php-posix for package: 1:php-pear-1.9.4-21.el7.noarch
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libzip.x86_64 0:0.10.1-8.el7 will be installed
---> Package php56w-process.x86_64 0:5.6.8-1.w7 will be installed
---> Package php56w-xml.x86_64 0:5.6.8-1.w7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libxslt.so.1(LIBXML2_1.0.24)(64bit) for package: php56w-xml-5.6.8-1.w7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libxslt.so.1(LIBXML2_1.0.22)(64bit) for package: php56w-xml-5.6.8-1.w7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libxslt.so.1(LIBXML2_1.0.18)(64bit) for package: php56w-xml-5.6.8-1.w7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libxslt.so.1(LIBXML2_1.0.13)(64bit) for package: php56w-xml-5.6.8-1.w7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libxslt.so.1(LIBXML2_1.0.11)(64bit) for package: php56w-xml-5.6.8-1.w7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libxslt.so.1()(64bit) for package: php56w-xml-5.6.8-1.w7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libexslt.so.0()(64bit) for package: php56w-xml-5.6.8-1.w7.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libxslt.x86_64 0:1.1.28-5.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Conflict: php56w-common-5.6.8-1.w7.x86_64 conflicts php-common < 5.5.0
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: php56w-common conflicts with php-common-5.4.16-23.el7_0.3.x86_64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

i dont want to remove

```
php56w-common
```

just for installing PECL-sphinx

i tried searching for php56w-pecl-sphinx by

```
yum search php56w | grep sphinx
```

but didnt find any packages .

so how do i install PECL SPHINX on php56w ?

Answer (score 0):

You must install php53 compatible sphinx You can try out the following php53 supported RPM

http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/23375981/dir/opensuse/com/php53-pecl-sphinx-1.3.0-2.1.x86_64.rpm.html tdownload the link at ftp://ftp.pbone.net/mirror/ftp5.gwdg.de/pub/opensuse/repositories/home:/airties:/server/SLE_11_SP2/x86_64/php53-pecl-sphinx-1.3.0-2.1.x86_64.rpm and try the below

```
yum install php53-pecl-sphinx-1.3.0-2.1.x86_64.rpm
```

Comment: # rpm -Uvh ftp://ftp.pbone.net/mirror/ftp5.gwdg.de/pub/opensuse/repositories/home:/airties:/server/SLE_11_SP2/x86_64/php53-pecl-sphinx-1.3.0-2.1.x86_64.rpm
Retrieving ftp://ftp.pbone.net/mirror/ftp5.gwdg.de/pub/opensuse/repositories/home:/airties:/server/SLE_11_SP2/x86_64/php53-pecl-sphinx-1.3.0-2.1.x86_64.rpm
warning: /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.bany7Q: Header V3 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 17197535: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
        php(zend-abi) = 20090626 is needed by php53-pecl-sphinx-1.3.0-2.1.x86_64
        php(api) = 20090626 is needed by php53-pecl-sphinx-1.3.0-2.1.x86_64